# Issue logging into SQL Server database on network from Docker container on Windows

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker

I am testing out Docker on Windows. I created a simple .net core console app that accesses a SQL Server on the network. We access SQL Server with `Integrated Security=True`, using our Windows credentials. Everything works fine outside of Docker.

I created an image and started a container.

During DB connect it throws this exception:

> SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

The issue is not with network accessibility, but with login onto SQL Server. I can ping SQL Server host from a container.

Connection string:

```
Data Source=<server name>;Initial Catalog=<db name>;Integrated Security=true;Connection Timeout=300
```

Any tips on how to mitigate this? I tried changing the connection string to user/pwd, but that didn't work.

Wondering if there is a way to start the container as a different windows account or somehow telling the container to start the process under a certain user?

Comment: I guess the issue might be that the docker container is not part of the same domain so it can't authenticate.  Try using a SQL Server id instead

Comment: Do you mean user id?

Comment: yup, create a sql server user id

Comment: Right... that would mean changing how we log into all our SqlServer instances. I'm trying to see if it's possible to leave that alone..

Comment: If you can get your docker container to join your AD domain, then integrated security should work.  otherwise, you're stuck, I'm afraid.

Comment: actually, there may be another way.  try to set up a windows credential for the container machine.  You'll still need a valid Windows account on the container and the same account as a SQL Server login.  but at least you shoudn't have to change your connection strings.

Comment: Thanks @user1443098 for the suggestion. I think this would be essentially a different user in the domain, so the only way this could work is with user/pwd sqlserver authentication, or am I missing something basic here?

Comment: SQL Server auth is simple.  The other way: Add your container to your AD Domain and the AD group to the SQL Server with appropriate access (both can be scripted, I believe) then your normal integrated security should work.  Or set up a windows credential mapping to an appropriate user in the container's domain

Answer (score 0):

Try connection: `"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=<db name>;User Id=SA;Password=<password>"`